# I don't want my VirtualHost responds to IP and domain

Tags: apache, configuration, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm trying to configure my virtualhost. The behaviour I would like to have is the following : when I type "http://www.mydomain.com", I display the "mydomain" page. When I type the IP "http://WW.XX.YY.ZZ", I display the default page in "/var/www".

Currently, I display the "mydomain" page whatever I type in the adress bar.

Here is my config files :

*apache2.conf :*

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

*sites-enabled/webmin.xxx.conf*

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/mydomain/www"
  <Directory "/home/mydomain/www">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way, when each time I restart apache, I've these errors :

```
* Restarting web server 
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Fri Apr 12 13:14:51 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Fri Apr 12 13:14:52 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And an entry in you /etc/hosts with :

YOUR_IP mydomain.com

it will help apache to find the correct ip address.